# How Content-Length can be measured in HTTP response?

Tags: c++, node.js, http

I converted zip file to binary format. While sending binary data as response found difference in Content-Length in http response headers.

Ex:In backend binary data size is 171 bytes. But in Content-Length its showing 194 Bytes. Why size difference happened for binary data over the network.

But while sending plain data didn't find any size difference.

> Response Header Info:
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
>   Age:0
>   Content-Length:194
>   Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Date:Thu, 27 Apr 2017 07:02:54 GMT
>   Via:1.1 localhost.localdomain
>   X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: Can you post the headers of the responses in question?

Comment: A wild guess is that your code is broken - maybe it's inserting carriage returns where the ZIP file has just a LF? Or it's applying a content-encoding of gzip on top? Hard to say without any details.

Comment: if you are setting the `Content-Length` yourself, then you are counting the body size incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't set content-length, it is calculated by the browser